# React Navigation Screen Skipped During Rendering Using `if` Statement, But Works Using Nested Ternaries

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

**Issue**: I am trying to conditionally render screens in a navigator, but it skips the first screen (GDPR), and goes to the main App screen directly even though the conditions are met.

code here:

```
if (!!firstLogin && !acceptedPrivacyPolicy) {
    console.log('rendering....', !!firstLogin, !acceptedPrivacyPolicy)
    return (
      <FirstLoginStack.Navigator 
      headerMode={'none'} 
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyleInterpolator: 
        CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
      }}>
        <FirstLoginStack.Screen name={'GDPR'} component={GDPR} />
        <FirstLoginStack.Screen name={'AppTabs'} component={AppTabs} />
      
    </FirstLoginStack.Navigator>
    )
  }
```

However, when I use a nested ternary, it works fine:

```
return ( 
    <AppMainStack.Navigator 
      headerMode={'none'} 
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyleInterpolator: 
        CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
    }}>
      {firstLogin ?
      <>
        {!acceptedPrivacyPolicy ? <AppMainStack.Screen name={'GDPR'} component={GDPR} /> : null}
        <AppMainStack.Screen name={'AppTabs'} component={AppTabs} />
      </>
      : <AppMainStack.Screen name={'AppTabs'} component={AppTabs} />
    }
    </AppMainStack.Navigator>
  )

Why is this the case?
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define different screens based on some condition. For example, if the user is signed in, we can define Home, Profile, Settings etc. If the user is not signed in, we can define SignIn and SignUp screens.

For example:

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
)
```

It's already defined workflow on [React Navigation Auth-Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)

Comment: thanks. yeah that's what i did in the second part. but my question is why the first one doesn't work

Comment: Because it needs stack navigator to render if your condition gets false, It would never render children defined in it so that wouldn't work at all

Comment: yeah but the conditions are true in both cases

Comment: It will not consider just `if`. It would need `else` also because when it only gets if condition then it would expect else also to render

Comment: appreciate the help. that's not true. "You should note that you don't have to include the else and the second curly brace block". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals

Comment: I'm not talking about general or `javascript`. I mean If the condition is in `<Stack.Navigator>` then

Comment: but all the first one does is if the conditions are met, then render the screens inside the stack navigator. it is pure javascript. am i missing something here?